# Network Topology on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, networking, topology

I could not understand the how the distance between the nodes became 0, 2, 4, 6.

Can anyone explain please.

As per the definitive guide,

For example, imagine a node n1 on rack r1 in data center d1. 
This can be represented as `/d1/r1/n1`. Using this notation, here are the distances for the four scenarios:

• `distance(/d1/r1/n1, /d1/r1/n1) = 0` (processes on the same node)

• `distance(/d1/r1/n1, /d1/r1/n2) = 2` (different nodes on the same rack)

• `distance(/d1/r1/n1, /d1/r2/n3) = 4` (nodes on different racks in the same data center)

• `distance(/d1/r1/n1, /d2/r3/n4) = 6` (nodes in different data centers).

• `distance(/d1/r1/n1, /d2/r3/n10) = ?`

[Network distance in Hadoop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opRW4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine your cluster as a tree with following levels:

- Abstract global root (Top or root)
- Data centers (1st level)
- Racks (2nd level)
- Nodes (3rd level or leaves)

If we draw this tree there should be something like this:

[image: Cluster topology]

Let's count distance between any circle and its parent as 1.

Then the distance between any two circles is the sum of their distance to their closest common ancestor or 0 for the same node.

So it'a always **6** for any two nodes in different data centres (like between /d1/r1/n1 and /d2/r4/n10).

Comment: Thanks @Maxteneff, that picture tells alot, nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"the distance between two nodes is the sum of their distances to their closest common ancestor" (Hadoop: The Definitive Guide 4th ed, page 70)

distance (/d1/r1/n1, /d2/r3/n10) = 6

The common ancestor between two nodes is /

so the distance from n1 to / is 3

and the distance from n10 to / is 3

the total is 6